# Изменение название переменной со ссылками на нее в одном xml файле

Tags: android-studio, xml

При попытке изменить название `view` в `xml` разметке в `Android Studio`, предлагается изменить все ссылки на неё в проекте, это понятно и логично. Однако, если эта `view` была скопирована из другого экрана приложения, она переименовывается и в том экране, откуда была скопирована. Мне же необходимо, чтобы изменялись только ссылки в данном `layout` и во фрагменте, связанным с этим экраном.

Предлагается посмотреть на список изменений в проекте после переименовывания переменной и исключить (exclude) или удалить (remove) эти изменения из текущего рефакторинга. Ни то, ни другое не помогает. При нажатии кнопки "Do Refactor" возникает ошибка, связанная с недавними изменениями в `layout`, предлагающая перезапустить рефакторинг. При перезапуске отсутсвует кнопка "Do Refactor". Как бы я ни старался, убрать лишние изменения в коде не получается.

Comment: а не проще если изменения затрагивают только один фрагмент, то просто поменять там название вручную и все?

Comment: Если от изменяемой вьюхи зависит много других, приходится обновлять достаточное количество ссылок на нее тоже

Comment: хм...да, про это я не подумал :)

Comment: Скопируйте файлы за проект, удалите их в проекте, переименуйте то, что хотите оставить неизменным, верните файлы, переименуйте нужные переменные. Профит!)